# How to filter CSV file on the web with VBA

Tags: vba, csv, web

I have auto-updated CSV file on the web:

https://data.rivm.nl/covid-19/COVID-19_aantallen_gemeente_per_dag.csv

And I need to connect it to my excel file. I can do it with Excel connections, but my problem is the size. I only need data for Amsterdam (Municipality_name = Amsterdam) and don't need other regions.

What is the best way to modify my Excel connection in order to not store all data in my file (only Amsterdam)?
Is there a way to use a kind of SQL to modify data before import to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query could do the work.

1
[image]

2

[image]

3 - Press ok

[image]

4 - Filter out Amsterdam and choose "Close & Load"

[image]

---

To edit your filtering you can click on the table -> Query -> Edit -> settings "wheel" and change Amsterdam to Ameland.

[image]